# Wrong user's page showing up after Oauth sign-in

Tags: authentication-authorization, social-network

I have a Drupal-based site that has Twitter Oauth logins.

Today, when I was testing out the site, I logged in with one Twitter account, and it showed me the user page of another user!

I tried logging in with various Twitter accounts, and they all took me to the same user's page. I also tried it from different devices and internet connections, just to be sure it wasn't something specific to my machine, but the same problem exhibited.

Any ideas where I can look for the source of the problem?

In case this is any help: I had a problem a week ago that was due to a corrupted file, and I simply had to open the .inc file, save it, and the site was working again.

I can try that for this problem too, but I have no idea how to debug it and identify which file could be the source of the problem, as I'm not at all familiar with Drupal.

Comment: Look like you have hard coded some info in your module or something.

Comment: Which module do you think it could be?

Comment: Have you made any modules ?